# This is the code to replace .txt files with each other so i would like to do this but i dont know where i am going wrong any tips?

Tags: php

this is the new code I am trying to replace the .txt file with the new car makes and model right now I am getting errors on those lines also I am entering the model and make but only adds to the txt files not replaces.

Notice: Undefined index: car_make in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\txtFiles\carcode.php on line 10

the contents of the.txt file are this '5bmw i5audii8' in one txt file but in the other, no contents are there but I only want one single.txt file with two forms

```
 <?PHP
    session_start();
    ?>
    
    <body>
    Car Make & Model
    <form name="submit" method="POST" action="carcode.php">
    Car Make <input type="text" name="car_make"> <br />
    Car Model <input type="text" name="car_model"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    <?PHP
    $car = $_POST['car_make'];
    $car2 = $_POST['car_model'];
    
    $Data = "Car make & Model.txt";
    
    $File = fopen($Data, 'a+');
    
    $name = $car;
    $name2 = $car2;
    fwrite($File, $name );
    fwrite($File, $name2);
    fclose($File);
    
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    Car Replacements
    <form name="submit" method="POST" action="carcode.php">
    Car Make <input type="text" name="car_make"> <br />
    Car Model <input type="text" name="car_model"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    
    <?PHP
    if (!empty($_POST['car_make'])&& !empty($_POST['car_model']))
    {
        $new_car_make=$_POST['car_make'];
        $new_car_model=$_POST['car_model'];
    
        $Data="New Car make & Model.txt";
    
        $haystack=file($Data);
    
        for($i=0; $i<count($haystack);$i++)
        {
            $haystack[$i]=str_ireplace($new_car_make,$new_car_model,$haystack[$i]);
    
        }
        file_put_contents($Data, $haystack);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: can you explain how this question is related to C#, or why you tagged this language?

Comment: Please only use the relevant language tags. I have removed C# tag because your question did not have anything to do with it.

Comment: i thought i removed it im very sorry for this

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “Unable to do this” is not a proper problem description. Explain what exactly you _want_ to happen here, and what happens instead.

Comment: Is this all supposed to be one script? Then why are there two `body` elements in there? And why are there two sections that write into the file? And why are you checking if the POST values you want to insert are actually set only in the second version? The first one will not have any POST values on the initial load of the page, so you will write _empty_ data into the file in that case.

Comment: this is because i needed two forms one for the make and model and the other for the replacement is that something I shouldn't be doing? I'm very new to coding so sorry in advance

Comment: You may have more than one form in a page quite legally, just have to make sure your code can deal with them

Comment: Please post the contents of the file "Car make & Model.txt" too.

Comment: i have now added the contents

Comment: For the 1st part (add data), it appears ok. For the 2nd part, what actually do you want to do ? (what do you want to do by "replace data" ?)

Comment: i want this form to replace the old so if someone makes a mistake they can replace the car model and make again

Comment: Please see me answer

Answer (score 0):

To add data, yes your codes fopen with 'a+' parameter is correct.
To replace existing data, we may use fopen with 'w+' (which clear the existing data and do the data insertion)

Since you are trying to work in one single form, you need to tell the system which action (add / replace) you want to execute. The simplest way is to use a hidden field (e.g. xaction) to let the php knows what part you want to do.

On the other hand, I also suspect that you want the "replacement" to work by replacing a particular make and model with a new one (instead of clearing the whole txt file, if that is the case I suggest you first read the contents of the txt file and then do a string replacement and after that save the data)

Try the codes below:

```
<?php
//    session_start();
    ?>
    
    <body>
    Car Make & Model (Add more data)
    <form name="submit" method="POST" action="carcode.php">
    Car Make <input type="text" name="car_make"> <br />
    Car Model <input type="text" name="car_model"> <br/>
    <input type=hidden name=xaction value="Add">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    <?php
    
    if ($_REQUEST["xaction"]=="Add") {
    $car = $_POST['car_make'];
    $car2 = $_POST['car_model'];
    
    $Data = "Car make & Model.txt";
    
    $File = fopen($Data, 'a+');
    
    $name = $car;
    $name2 = $car2;
    fwrite($File, " " );
    fwrite($File, $name );
    fwrite($File, " " );
    fwrite($File, $name2);
    fclose($File);}
    
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    Car Replacements (replace whole file data with the following new data)
    <form name="submit" method="POST" action="carcode.php">
    Car Make <input type="text" name="car_make"> <br />
    Car Model <input type="text" name="car_model"> <br/>
    <input type=hidden name=xaction value="Replace">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    
     <?php
    if ($_REQUEST["xaction"]=="Replace") { 
    $car = $_POST['car_make'];
    $car2 = $_POST['car_model'];
    
    $Data = "Car make & Model.txt";
    
    $File = fopen($Data, 'w+');
    
    $name = $car;
    $name2 = $car2;
    fwrite($File, " " );
    fwrite($File, $name );
    fwrite($File, " " );    
    fwrite($File, $name2);
    fclose($File);
    }
    ?>
```

1. For your information, I have commented the line "session_start()" because in your case you do not need to work on any session variables, but if other part of your code require to work on session variables, please un-comment this line)
2. Actually the manipulation of insertion / update / deletion of data should be performed by using a `database`. If you have time , please try to use database instead of using a `txt` file to do the job.